# How to use a text input binding between my parent and my child component?

Tags: angular

I have an input binding between my parent and my child component.

I want my child component to show up a text, which is input by the parent component. But the browser is not showing the text. How can I make the browser show up the text immediately and what am I doing wrong?

child component controller:

```
export class myChild {
    @Input()
    public text: String = "";

    public showText: String = "";
    
    constructor() {
        this.showText = text;
    }
}
```

child component html:

```
<p>{{showText}}</p>
```

parent component html:

```
<my-child [text]="my test text"></my-child>
```

Comment: `[text]="'my test text'"` or `[text]='my test text'` or `text="my test text"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input binding works perfectly. So why does your application not show up your desired text "my test text"? What you are experiencing is a race-condition between your child components construction and the receive of it's input.
Currently, this is happing:

1. Your child component is injected into your parents component and your childs components lifecycle has started with its construction.
2. The constructor of your child component runs it's code block, which is `this.showText = text`. At this point, your input variable `text` has its default starting value `""`.
3. Your child component's @Input() binding for your `text` is executed. Now your text has the received input `"my test text"`. Unfortunetly, your variable `this.showText = text;` has already run before.

This is why your child component has the empty string in its variable `showText`.

**Solution:**
Instead of setting your showText variable inside the constructor, you can create a Input setter method inside your child component's controller, which will be executed undependently from your components lifecycle:

```
child component:
export class myChild {
    public showText: string = "";
    constructor() {}
    
    @Input()
    public set text(value: string) {
        this.showText = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need really make a setter:`@Input() set text(value: string) {this.showText = value;}` -see the "set"-. BTW, why not use in child simply:`<p>{{text}}</p>` (then you needn't make a setter)?

Comment: you are right. I adjusted the code. Thanks!